# Lie Derivative computation

Tags: lie-derivative

On $\mathbb{R}^{4}$
  with coordinates $x_{1},y_{2},x_{2},y_{2}$
  consider the 2-form $\omega=dx_{1}\wedge dy_{1}+dx_{2}\wedge dy_{2}$
 . GIven a smooth $f$
  on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$
 , let $X$
  be the vector field: $\vec{X}=f_{y_{1}}\partial_{x_{1}}-f_{x_{1}}\partial_{y_{1}}+f_{y_{2}}\partial_{x_{2}}-f_{x_{2}}\partial_{y_{2}}$

Compute the lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_{X}\omega$
  of $\omega$
  w.r.t. $\vec{X}$

My Answer: $\mathcal{L}_{X}\omega=i_{X}\left(\textrm{d}\omega\right)+\textrm{d}\left(i_{X}\omega\right)$.

Now, $\textrm{d}\omega=0$
 , since the coefficient functions of the two elementary 2-forms in $\omega$
  are both constants, and hence, have partial derivatives of $0$. Thus, the $i_{X}\left(\textrm{d}\omega\right)$
  term vanishes.

As for the other term, since $\omega$
  is a 2-form, letting $\vec{v}=\left(v_{1},v_{1}^{\prime},v_{2},v_{2}^{\prime}\right)$
  in the given coordinates, $i_{X}\omega$
  is the one-form: 
$\left(i_{X}\omega\right)\left(\vec{v}\right)\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\omega\left(\vec{X},\vec{v}\right)=\left(dx_{1}\wedge dy_{1}\right)\left(\vec{X},\vec{v}\right)+\left(dx_{2}\wedge dy_{2}\right)\left(\vec{X},\vec{v}\right)$
$=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
dx_{1}\left(\vec{X}\right) & dx_{1}\left(\vec{v}\right)\\
dy_{1}\left(\vec{X}\right) & dy_{1}\left(\vec{v}\right)
\end{array}\right|+\left|\begin{array}{cc}
dx_{2}\left(\vec{X}\right) & dx_{2}\left(\vec{v}\right)\\
dy_{2}\left(\vec{X}\right) & dy_{2}\left(\vec{v}\right)
\end{array}\right|$

$=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
f_{y_{1}} & dx_{1}\left(\vec{v}\right)\\
-f_{x_{1}} & dy_{1}\left(\vec{v}\right)
\end{array}\right|+\left|\begin{array}{cc}
f_{y_{2}} & dx_{2}\left(\vec{v}\right)\\
-f_{x_{2}} & dy_{2}\left(\vec{v}\right)
\end{array}\right|$

$=f_{y_{1}}dy_{1}\left(\vec{v}\right)+f_{x_{1}}dx_{1}\left(\vec{v}\right)+f_{y_{2}}dy_{2}\left(\vec{v}\right)+f_{x_{2}}dx_{2}\left(\vec{v}\right)$
$=\textrm{d}f\left(\vec{v}\right)$

Hence, $\mathcal{L}_{X}\omega=\textrm{d}\left(\textrm{d}f\right)=0$
 . 
Is this right?
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? The computation looks good.

Comment: My question is: IS THIS RIGHT? xD

A solution I have for the problem applies the leibniz rule property of the lie derivative, and gets a horrible answer as the result. You're telling me this is right? :D?